# BASH while line numbers in file is smaller than x

Tags: linux, bash, wc

i want to make a loop that reads some files
and i want it to stop when wc output is smaller than 5 in this case
the file "file" contains the names of the files that will be worked on

```
for i in `cat file`
do

echo printing $i ...
a=`wc $i`
while [ $a -gt 5 ]
do
echo 3
sleep 10
done

done
```

this part is not working

```
a=`wc $i`
while [ $a -gt 5 ]
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? You have created an infinite loop, because the `$a` is not reevaluated inside the `while` statement. Maybe you wanted `if` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=$(wc -l $i|awk '{print $1}')
```

try this?

Comment: Or just `a=$(wc -l < $i)` -- this way, the filename is not printed

Answer (score 3):

Your going to want to use `wc -l` to get the line count of the file. Also you will want to decrement $a so you don't have an infinite loop.